# Struggles to make RcppArmadillo work with openMP in R package

Tags: r-package, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I am working on a R package that relies on the functionality of the armadillo C++ library through RcppArmadillo and have troubles making it work in parallel with openMP. So my questions are about the c++ side of things and armadillo and then the Rcpp side.

The armadillo documentation is not very detailed on how to make it work and the overall process is very much machine and compiler dependent from what I understand, which makes it quite a challenge.

After much struggle, I am able to run a pure c++ script locally using the original Mac compiler (clang++), armadillo and openMP by executing the following command in terminal:

```
clang++ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp arma_omp.cpp -o arma_omp -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include -lomp -larmadillo
```

The `-Xpreprocessor` bit was the hardest to find, and I more or less understand the action of the other options. However, I cannot be sure that armadillo uses the number of threads I set with `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=n`.So my first question is:
**Is it possible to know for sure how many threads armadillo uses for an operation ?**
I would think there could be a function inside the library that when called gives this number, but couldn't find it.

Additionally, I am wondering **if there is a good way to benchmark this sort of things in c++ ?** For example having a loop that executes the same operation with a different number of threads and then outputs the times. So far, I found a simple way using the Clock from standard library, as suggested [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/timing-your-code/), but something more automated would be good to know.

Now to the rcpparmadillo side of things. When compiling my package, I created a makevars file, which from my understanding is a way to provide the right compiler options that you would manually type in a command line locally. However, I am not sure what is the right set of parameters to use and the few responses on the topic I found here did not really make it clear.
One option I tried was `PKG_CXXFLAGS= -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include -lomp` but I am pretty certain this is wrong. And commands being executed when I run a check on the package mention that the options I submit were not used.

So my questions are,
**What are the right parameters to use to have openMP with RcppArmadillo in a R package?**
I realise that this is machine dependent, and would need some manual settings done by future users, but I am at least trying to have it run locally.

**How do I then control the number of threads being used ?**
Ideally, using RcppParallel::setThreadOptions(n_threads), but should this work ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: All this works out of the box on Linux, but macOS has always been a little special because of what it does or require to its toolchain.  I would recommend you post on the rcpp-devel list: several knowledgable macOS users are subscribe and may see it there.